# How to expand root partion in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: partitioning, 19.10

I want to expand my root partition `/dev/sda5` by adding unallocated space. Primary Partition is 30 GB and I want to add 20 GB more so that it can be 50 GB. I tried using gparted and live CD but doesn't work.

[image: my system partion]

Comment: Do it from a LiveUSB. But you'll need to reinstall grub, because you move the start point of `/`.

Comment: @Pilot6 We never got an answer from a previous OP where you indicated that a GRUB install would be required. I've put together a similar answer here... let's see if a GRUB install is required, or not.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hello? Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have:

A Primary Partition, which contains

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda4
Unallocated space
```

and a Secondary Partition, which contains

```
/dev/sda5
```

You'll need to seek advice on shrinking your Primary Partition. I'm not going to get more detailed, because I'm just guessing.

Re your picture: Observe the keys next to `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5`. They're indications that these partitions are mounted, and that `gparted` won't change `/dev/sda` while they're mounted.

Comment: dev/sda 1,2,3,4 are windows partion and dev/sda4 is ubuntu. Want to merge unallocated space to dev/sda4.

Comment: This has incorrect information, AND it doesn't answer the question. :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I believe that you mean you actually want to increase /dev/sda5 (not /dev/sda4)...**

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda5 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda5 all the way right
- click the Apply icon